# Formatted string in scanf() in C

Tags: c, input, formatting, scanf, format-specifiers

Just like `printf()`, I was trying to use optional specifiers in `scanf()` format string. I tried to use the width and precision specifier. Now in `printf()` it simply reserves the columns and print according to these specifiers but what happens with `scanf()`? Like what is meaning of `%3d` and `%3.3f` here? Is this even relevant in case of `scanf()`? I have a little idea that width in this case represents the number of characters that are to be read for some particular format but not sure. Below code explains this further:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
float b;
printf("Enter Numbers:\n");
scanf("%3d %3.3f",&a,&b);
printf("Entered Numbers are\n");
printf("%d %f",a,b);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` doesn't have a "precision" specifier.  Compare [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) with [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Okay but what if i forcefully try to do it, just like the above case, Is it UB or something else?

Comment: `scanf` is a C function, not a part of the C language itself.  If it was written properly, there shouldn't be any way to cause UB by merely providing it input.  Very likely, it will just ignore the precision specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified in the comments that what  you really want to know is '*what if i forcefully try to do it*' ... Here are the results (with **Clang**)

```
warning: invalid conversion specifier '.'
```

and

```
warning: data argument not used by format string
```

The program compiles , however, since these are just warnings.

Upon executing the binary, and entering the variables asked for:

1. The `"%d"` for `a` gets stored properly.
2. Regardless of what value is entered, the `" %3.3f "` for `b` always stores `0.000000`

In short, the it does what almost any other code that compiles with warnings does - **not behave as intended**. This is neither undefined, nor unspecified behaviour, but it is *wrong*.

Suggestion : Refrain from asking questions that are of the nature ' *what happens if I try to compile this* '. Just try and see for yourself !